# Upgraded to 3.6.1. and cannot open my website anymore

Tags: upgrade

I upgraded to 3.6.1. and all the sudden I cannot open my site anymore. 
Any suggestion on how to solve this?

Comment: Please add [debug information](http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress) to your **question** to make answers possible.

Comment: [*`OMGWTFBBQ, WordPress 3.6 broke everything? Don't panic!`*](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/troubleshooting-wordpress-36-master-list)

Answer (score 1):

Disable your plugins via FTP, by renaming the plugins folder. I found MANY plugins cause a "white page" issue. Need to wait for upgraded plugins or WP fix.